# Create different number of items inside a ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

In this adapter, you'll have to fill your items to an ID already created in the layout.

How do I proceed to create new Imageview(or other) inside this adapter, when each item inside my importet list have a different amount of images or text for each listrow?

Example:

I want to fill inn a X number of pictures where the black/white boxes are, depending on each item.

[image]

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context context;
        List<RowItem> rowItems;

        public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
            this.context = context;
            this.rowItems = items;
        }

        /*private view holder class*/
        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView txtTitle;
            TextView txtDesc;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);

            holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
            holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return rowItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return rowItems.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
        }
    }
```

Comment: put what you need inside R.layout.list_item, and show or hide as your convinience